# Is there a value in unifying animation lengths in turn based game?

Tags: game-design, animation, turn-based

It might be a small detail, but I'm wondering if there is a significant impact on the game feel between scenario where for example all characters in a game have the same attack animation length and scenario where each character may have different attack animation length.

Has there ever been anyone exploring such topic?

Answer (score 1):

In a turn based game, your intuition is probably correct - it's a small detail. More important is making sure none of them are too long. Especially if they aren't skippable, overlong animations can turn an asset (beautiful animation) into a liability (annoyed players feeling like their time is being wasted watching the same attack for the millionth time).

If you have simultaneous animations (i.e. defender parrying an attack), I suppose a uniform animation length might make synchronizing them easier, but that sounds a bit like premature optimization.

In contrast, if it was real time, animation lengths matter a lot. For instance, in a platformer, different jump animations could make some characters feel floaty. In a fighting game or brawler, animations lengths can be critical to strategy of high performance game play.

Answer (score 1):

It can make sense from a development perspective. When all animation sequences are unified, your animation management code can be a lot more concise.

From a user experience perspective: You want attack animations in a turn-based game to be short and sweet anyway. Remember that players will see these animations *a lot*. A super-elaborate 30 second attack cutscene might be awesome the first time you see it, but after 10 or 20 repetitions it just becomes tedious and the players will start to google for a mod to get rid of them. This might be an extreme example, but the same also applies to *slightly* longer than average attack animations. In the long run, players will start to detest the units which just steal their precious time with their longer attack animations. By putting a self-imposed time restriction on your attack animations, you avoid that.

There is also a more subtle UX effect: An unified animation length can put the player into a steady and regular clickclick-watch-clickclick-watch-clickclick-watch rhythm. This puts the player into an immersive, trance-like flow-state where they are completely focused on the game. This is usually a very pleasurable experience for the player. When that interaction rhythm is more irregular due to different lengths of watch-phases, the player will have a harder time to "get into the flow". This is more of a subconscious effect. So the test players will likely to be unable to tell why, but they will be able to tell that *something* is off with the how the game feels.

Comment: I was suspecting that getting player into the flow state might be a thing with unified lengths. Has there been any case where someone actually noticed such thing, or is it something we both suspect without any evidence?